# Python XML parsing junk error - multiple encoding lines

Tags: python, xml, element

I'm getting a junk error when I try and parse an XML file. It's a file which contains 100s of merged XML files, resulting in 100s of  tags. Also means that it doesn't contain any proper root element. So I have two issues, how do I read the file such that it won't error? And how do I fix the issue of no root element?

I've been trying to play around with it for a while but to no avail, I've tried reading it line by line and converting to a list but then I'm not sure what to do with it....

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your issue?

Comment: 1. Put the file through a checker to ensure it is formatted correctly
2. Clean it up manually, sometimes a bit of elbow grease is needed. If there are no clear patterns, trying to programmatically resolve this is not going to work imho

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: how do I read the file such that it won't error?

Use a `try: ... except:` block while reading, for example:

```
try:
    element = root.next_element()
except Exception as exp:
    print(exp)
```

> **Question**: how do I fix the issue of no root element?

Add a `<root>` Tag enclosing a given `XML` Table or Part:

```
xml = '<root>{}</root>'.format(xml)
```